# Changing background color of selected item in kendo ui mutiselect angular

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2

> I am trying to execute kendo ui multiselect some what like code below.But i need to change the background color of selected item from red color to some other color.I tried giving custom css in popupsettings but still it is not working.
>       Most googled answers are in jquery but i need it in angular 4.Could you please help me out

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<p>Custom values are <strong>enabled</strong>. Type a custom value.</p>

<p>primitive data</p>
<div class="example-wrapper">
    <kendo-multiselect
        [data]="sizes"
        [value]="selectedSizes"
        [allowCustom]="true"
        (valueChange)="onSizeChange($event)"
    >
    <ng-template kendoMultiSelectCustomItemTemplate let-customText>
        <strong>{{ customText }}</strong>
    </ng-template>
    </kendo-multiselect>
</div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
public sizes: Array<string> = [ "Small", "Medium", "Large" ];
public selectedSizes: Array<string> = [];

public onSizeChange(value) {
    this.selectedSizes = value;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following CSS to your component:

```
::ng-deep .k-item.k-state-selected {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kendo solution.

```
:host ::ng-deep .k-state-selected {
     background-color: green !important; 
}
```

url: https://www.progress.com/blogs/options-for-styling-components-in-kendo-ui-builder